# Trying to graph a function

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to graph this function, the plot shows up but has no content any help would be appreciated.

```
1 + 2 v^2 (1 - Cos[x]) + 2 vSin[x]
Manipulate[Plot[T, {x, 0, 6 Pi}], {v, 1, 100}]
```

Comment: What is `T`? Why are you multiplying something by your `Manipulate` call? Read the docs.

Comment: May be you meant this `T0[v_] := 1 + 2 v^2 (1 - Cos[x]) + 2 v Sin[x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[T0[v], {x, 0, 6 Pi}],
 {v, 1, 100}
 ]` You need to define a function first to plot it.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple,because v is not set here, mathematica does not know this is the variable for manipulate.To solve this all you have to do is to write the function inside the manipulate,like this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[1 + 2 v^2 (1 - Cos[x]) + 2 v*Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}], {v, 1, 100}]
```